# How to put the text inside react-icons component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an icon as a component, I need to put the text inside of it. Here is what I have:

```
<span className={s['manaBtn']}>
    <FiHexagon /><span className={s['manaBtn__text']}>{props.value}</span>
</span>
```

The styles

```
.manaBtn {
        position: relative;
    &__text {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform: translate(50%, -50%);
        z-index: 2;
    }
}
```

The result [image]
It is not about the styling, I can apply it on my own. I'm asking is there a way to make this values as children or smth like this.

Comment: ` <FiHexagon />` is the icon which is shown in the background?

Comment: <FiHexagon />` is the icon which is shown in the background

Comment: Was this icon component built by you?

Comment: no it is from react-icons library

Comment: have you built this icon yourself? If yes then you can configure it and send the prop of `value={props.value}` and can use it as child.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new component:

```
const customIcon = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <FiHexagon/>
      <div>props.value</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Style the divs according to your needs.

Then pass `value` as a prop: `<customIcon value=0/>`